# How to create CHECK constraints in Informix?

Tags: sql, informix

I need to create validations in my fields (columns) in Informix tables.  Inside SQL Server, the names are CHECK (for example: CHECK (Age>=18))

How to create in Informix, or, what's the similar syntax in Informix?

Comment: Whats does "nama" means?.Moreover you can do this validations before you insert them into the tables

Comment: There's one idiosyncrasy in Informix which is that the constraint name follows the constraint rather than preceding it as in Standard SQL.  That is, in Standard SQL, you might write `CHECK CONSTRAINT check_age (Age >= 18)` but in Informix, you have to write `CHECK (Age >= 18) CONSTRAINT check_age` instead.  You can add the constraints when you create the table, or use ALTER TABLE to add them later.

Answer (score 1):

If you want add check constraint you could do it in two ways:

1) The next example adds a new unit_price column to the items table and includes a check constraint to ensure that the entered value is greater than 0:

```
ALTER TABLE items 
   ADD (unit_price MONEY (6,2) CHECK (unit_price > 0));
```

2) To create a constraint that checks values in more than one column, use the ADD CONSTRAINT clause. The following example builds a constraint on the column that was added in the previous example. The check constraint now spans two columns in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (unit_price < total_price);
```

[Have a look at the doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0306.htm)